# Adding a user to MySQL with 'name'@'%' fails with ERROR 1396

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1, users

I just tried to add a new user to MySQL using

```
CREATE USER 'name'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '...'
```

However, it fails with the following error:

```
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'name'@'%'
```

Adding the user just for localhost works fine:

```
CREATE USER 'name'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '...'
```

I have no clue what could be the problem. I'd be grateful for any ideas.

(I'm using `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.66`.)

Comment: I faced the similar issue, while CREATE / DROP the user, I verified all the grant tables for user information, I could not find any user info, I tried revoking all access and dropped the user, after sometime, the operation works, without doing any changes, I written my detailed answer here https://www.rathishkumar.in/2018/10/Error-1396-HY000-Operation-CREATE-DROP-USER-failed-for-user-host.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-user.html) if you ommit the @'hostname' (that is CREATE USER 'name') MySQL will interpret it as it had a @'%'. The error message you provided suggests that there is already a user 'name'@'%' in the system:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'name'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'test';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> CREATE USER 'name'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'test';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'name'@'%'
mysql> CREATE USER 'name' IDENTIFIED BY 'test';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'name'@'%'
```

If you delete the user and still get the message, try running FLUSH PRIVILEGES.

Also see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555328/error-1396-hy000-operation-create-user-failed-for-jacklocalhost) for additional info.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this same error while using mysql:5.7 docker image. Main mistake was trying to create `root` user which exists by default. 
More information: https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/129

As given in the above link, solution was to NOT set `MYSQL_USER` and `MYSQL_PASSWORD` in the environment variables while starting the docker image.

Comment: This helped me a lot! I didn't know why I couldn't connect to the DB in docker and never suspected this was the reason.